# No Console Log Output When Clicking Plus Icon in Unordered List

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an ul (unordered list) which contains several li (list items) when I click on the + sign left to li, console log should output "description expanded" For the two first li, it works just fine, but not for any other li's. The html code by default includes only 2 li's. any li after that is added through the form. However, any new li does not produce the console log output. Which means they're not responding to clicks. I'm using jQuery to listen for click events. When clicking on the  icon. 
project link http://pctechtips.org/apps/todo/

```
//variables
//todoList array to hold (title, description) for every todo tiem
var todoList = []; //{title: "value", desc: "value"},
var numId = 2; //num is for desc paragraph id eg <p id="plus-3">

/*
 * Script main body
 */
 $(document).ready(function() { 
    //hide form when doc loads first time
    $("#submit-form").hide();
    //hide list item description <p>
    $(".item-desc").hide();

    //listener for show hide form functionality
     $("#add-todo").click(function() {
        toggleForm();
        return false; //return false to prevent page reload
     });

     //listener for add new item form (submit button)
     $(".btn").click(function() {
        console.log("submit item");
        addToList();
     });

     //listener for expanding li description
     $(".plus").click(function() {
        console.log("description expanded")
        var plusId = $(this).attr("id"); //grabbing id of plus sign
        showDescription(plusId);
        return false;
     });
 });

 //functionality for show / hide form
 function toggleForm() {
    if($("#submit-form").is(":hidden")) {
        console.log("form exapnded");
        $("#submit-form").show("slow");
        $("#form-icon").removeClass("fa-plus-square-o");
        $("#form-icon").addClass("fa-minus-square-o");
    }
    else {
        console.log("form hidden");
        $("#submit-form").hide("slow");
        $("#form-icon").removeClass("fa-minus-square-o");
        $("#form-icon").addClass("fa-plus-square-o");
    }   
 } 

 //add new item to todo list items
 function addToList() {
    numId++;
    //getting data from input fields
    var todoTitle = $("#todo-title").val();
    var todoDesc  = $("#todo-desc").val();
    //checking user input
    if(todoTitle == "" || todoDesc == "") {
        alert("fill in all fields!");
    }
    else {
        console.log(todoTitle + "\n" + todoDesc);
        //adding values to array
        todoList.push({title: todoTitle, desc: todoDesc},);
        //adding new li to ul   
        var ul = document.getElementById("list");
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        $(li).addClass("list-group-item justify-content-between align-items-center");
        $(li).append(($('<i id="plus-'+numId+'" class="plus fa fa-plus-square-o left" aria-hidden="true"></i>')));
        $(li).append(($('<span class="left marg-left">'+todoTitle+'</span>')));
        $(li).append(($('<i class="fa fa-trash-o right" aria-hidden="true"></i>')));
        $(li).append(($('<i class="fa fa-pencil right marg-right pr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>')));
        ul.appendChild(li); 
    }   
 }

 //expanding description under for each todo
 function showDescription(plusId) {
    //getting the number from id
    var num = plusId.substring(plusId.indexOf("-")+1); 
    //checking for hide / show description paragraph
    if($("#desc-"+num).is(":hidden")) {
        $("#desc-"+num).show("slow");
        $("#desc-"+num).removeClass("fa-plus-square-o");
        $("#desc-"+num).addClass("fa-minus-square-o");
    }
    else {
        $("#desc-"+num).hide("slow");
        $("#desc-"+num).removeClass("fa-minus-square-o");
        $("#desc-"+num).addClass("fa-plus-square-o");
    }
 }
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TodoList App</title>
    <!-- bootstrap, fontawsome cdn -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- local stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <!-- jquery cdn -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- local javascript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/todo.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <!-- navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-drak bg-dark mb-4">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><i class="fa fa-thumb-tack" aria-hidden="true"></i> Todo<strong>List</strong></a>
        </nav>
    <!-- /navbar -->
    <!-- todoList -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="add-item text-white text-center col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-8 mb-4">
        <a id="add-todo" class="new-todo text-white text-center" href=""><i id="form-icon" class="fa fa-plus-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Enter new todo item</a>
        <div id="submit-form" class="form-hide text-center col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-8">
            <form class="">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="todo-title" placeholder="Todo Title" value="Pay Car Insurance">        
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="todo-desc" placeholder="Todo Description" value="This is to pay car insurance">
              </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg col-12">Submit Todo</button>               
            </form>                 
        </div>
        <!-- horizontal line -->
            <hr>
        <!-- list items -->
        <h1 class="heading-4">Todo List Items</h1>
        <ul id="list" class="list-group mt-4 pb-4">
          <li class="list-group-item  justify-content-between align-items-center">
           <i id="plus-1" class="plus fa fa-plus-square-o left" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
           <span class="left marg-left">Pay Car Insurance </span>         
           <i class="fa fa-trash-o right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
           <i class="fa fa-pencil right marg-right pr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         </li>
         <p id="desc-1" class="item-desc bg-white">Helloooooooooo this is description</p>
          <li class="list-group-item  justify-content-between align-items-center">
           <i id="plus-2" class="plus fa fa-plus-square-o left" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
           <span class="left marg-left">Pay Car Insurance </span><i class="fa fa-trash-o right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
           <i class="fa fa-pencil right marg-right pr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>           
         </li>
         <p id="desc-2" class="item-desc bg-white">Helloooooooooo this is description</p>
        </ul>
    </div>  
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$(document).on("click", ".plus", function() {
    console.log("description expanded")
    var plusId = $(this).attr("id"); //grabbing id of plus sign
    showDescription(plusId);
    return false;
 });
```

Instead of having a static click listener defined at document load.

Answer (score 0):

ok for dynamically added elements the even listener needs to be defined at the root / document level. so

```
$("class").on("click", function() { });
```

will not work. It needs to be

```
$(document).on("click", ".class", function() { });
```

Thanks to "MADDY BLACKLISTED" above pointed me in right directions

Comment: Edited the answer. Thanks for pointing. Please accept the answer so that this could help others in the future. Thanks.